# How can I run an ssh client that forwards ports only once and then (automatically) stops listening?

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

When running `ssh -R 2222:localhost:22 remotehost`, the ssh client will keep listening at port 2222 on `remotehost` regardless of the number of existing tcp connections to port 2222 on `remotehost` that are being forwarded by this client on to `localhost` port 22.

Is there a way to configure a port-forwarding ssh client that forwards *only the first connection it gets* and then *stops listening* on the forwarding port (without disturbing the existing forwarded tcp connection)?  (The user does not have permissions to change configuration of the ssh server on `remotehost`.)

I am trying to get a behavior similar to [`socat`](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/)'s `tcp4-listen` (which does not accept a second connection unless a `fork` option is present), but over a secure ssh channel.

**Edit/addendum**: My question can be explained by a hypothetical "ssh feature request". Suppose ssh had an `ssh_config` client option **`ForwardLimit num,mins`** under which ssh stops listening temporarily if the number of connections reaches `num` in the last `mins` minutes, or permanently if `mins` is zero. (This is like firewall rate-control, but enforced by the ssh client running in userspace.) Then the question could be solved by adding the option `ForwardLimit 1,0`.  But, since such a feature does not exist, I am looking for the best possible workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way, using OpenSSH, to close an opened remote forwarding without closing the *ssh* connection that initiated it. It should be easy to integrate it in OP's exact use case.

This requires the use of the [`ControlMaster`](https://manpages.debian.org/ssh_config.5#ControlMaster) option, its companion [`ControlPath`](https://manpages.debian.org/ssh_config.5#ControlPath) (which should be further taylored using adequate [tokens](https://manpages.debian.org/ssh_config.5#TOKENS), but kept simple here) and the [`-O`](https://manpages.debian.org/ssh.1#O) parameter of `ssh`.

> `ControlMaster`
>
> Enables the sharing of multiple sessions over a single network connection. When set to `yes`, ssh(1) will listen for connections on a
> control socket specified using the `ControlPath` argument. Additional
> sessions can connect to this socket using the same `ControlPath` with
> `ControlMaster` set to `no` (the default). These sessions will try to
> reuse the master instance's network connection rather than initiating new ones
> [...]

> `-O` *ctl_cmd*
>
> Control an active connection multiplexing master process. When the -O
> option is specified, the ctl_cmd argument is interpreted and passed to
> the master process. Valid commands are: “check” (check that the master
> process is running), “forward” (request forwardings without command
> execution), **“cancel” (cancel forwardings)**, “exit” (request the master
> to exit), and “stop” (request the master to stop accepting further
> multiplexing requests).

The first ssh command should use the option `ControlMaster=yes` (or `auto`):

```
ssh -o ControlMaster=yes -o ControlPath=/tmp/mysshcontrolpath -R 2222:localhost:22 remotehost
```

Any further *ssh* command interacting with the master *ssh* connection should use `ControlMaster=no` (or also `auto`) and use exactly the same `ControlPath`.

Wait for incoming ssh connection somehow (that's the part needing integration) and run the following command. If the same user is connecting back, this following command could even be executed through the incoming connection since it's now executing on the local system (no secret is needed, but it's mandatory to access the `ControlPath` socket with the same user):

```
ssh -o ControlMaster=no -o ControlPath=/tmp/mysshcontrolpath -O cancel -R 2222:localhost:22 remotehost
```

Beside a small (if using non interactive authentication) race window which could allow a 2nd connection to succeed while the first was ongoing, if this is run immediately by the incoming *ssh* connection, the listening socket would be closed after it connected successfully preventing further connections.

This command doesn't attempt to connect to `remotehost` (with `-O`, the remote host parameter is still needed for the syntax but gets ignored): it will merely connect (via local UNIX socket) to the master *ssh* still running and ask it to close the specified remote forwarding (`-O cancel -R 2222:localhost:22`).

It could also be used to add an other one or the same after it was closed, with: `-O forward -R 2222:localhost:22`). Actually using `-O ...` is the only way to alter forwardings when not being the master *ssh* command (and using the `ControlPath` created by such master ssh): other ssh commands used in this way can't have their *own* forwarding since they are reusing the master *ssh* to connect.

See also `ControlPersist` which could be useful depending on the use case: whether the initial (master) *ssh* will stay open or not once finished. If enabled, it could probably be used along the `-N` option to have a sort of on-demand forwarding mechanism. Likewise `-O exit` could have its use too.

Comment: Thanks. I was already aware of the `ControlMaster`/`ControlPath` method you outline. Maybe nothing better exists. If so, then it confirms my suspicion that ssh does not have an internal feature that limits the number of forwarded connections and then stops listening. BTW, we can further automate by injecting an additional forwarding step:  In the first `ssh -R` replace the local side port 22 by 1111 (say), and also in parallel run a no-fork `socat` on `localhost` that forwards 1111 to 22 and execs the `ssh -O cancel` command upon incoming connection.  But the race window will still exist.

Comment: Just to clarify my earlier comment "the race window will still exist" even if we inject a no-fork `socat`: With the injection of the additional forwarding via an "only once" `socat`, a second forwarded tcp connection cannot be *completed*, but an outside host attempting a second connection to `remotehost` at port 2222 can still receive another tcp `ACK` during the race window. Or may be not?

Comment: You are looking for a precise method/solution (accept connection only once) to an unknown (to us) problem. If you explained what is this unknown problem you are actually attempting to solve that can't even suffer any race condition etc. maybe somebody else would come with an entirely different answer that would solve this yet unknown problem. Be careful to not step into the [XY](https://xyproblem.info/) [problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: The parenthetical "automatically" in the question title and the `socat` reference in the question body should indicate my problem, but I agree that it should be more explicit. Essentially I want a firewall-like rate-control / connection-limit for ssh port forwarding (`ssh -R`/`-L`) configured from the client side in userland (user has no root access and so no control over sshd or the firewall on `remotehost`). I will edit my question. I will also edit your answer to add the automation/integration from my first comment, and finally I will accept your answer. Sound good?

Comment: You forced my hand with this addition. I'm accepting this change. Don't do additional change on my answer. This should have been done in its own answer.

Comment: You're right, my additions should have been in a separate answer. My apologies. I won't do any more change on your answer for now, but to fix the mess I created, I propose one last "revert-back" change to bother you with (I will not make any change unless you agree).  Here is the proposed change:  For the edit/content I added at the end of your answer, I will remove it entirely and put it in my separate answer, and for the two reference/pointer notes I added ("Note added by OP") in relevant places in your answer, I will update them by replacing "See edit below by OP" with "See answer by OP".

Comment: I'll just revert all the changes and you're good to add your own answer: I think that's how this should have been done.

Comment: @adgadg also, I understand my answer is not the solution you're looking after and that what you added is more like it. You could also switch the accepted answer to yours if it suits your needs.

Comment: I have added my answer,  reset the "accepted" status on your answer, and plan to make my answer the accepted one, although I am still not fully sure about which answer should be the final accepted one.  Maybe someone will have a better answer.  Otherwise, the best solution may still be that you link to my answer in relevant places and I accept your answer?

Answer (score 0):

This answer extends @A.B's answer based on ssh's `-O cancel` action.  Here the cancel action is **auto-triggered** ***at tcp level*** immediately when the first forwarded connection starts. Moreover, any second connection is prevented even during the window in which the first connection has started but the cancel action has not yet finished.

(Note: The hard-coded forwarding port numbers 2222 (remote listen port) and 22 (local target port) are just examples; general remote forwarding will use arbitrary tcp ports (`-R remoteport:localhost:localport`).)

**Making the first forwarding connection auto-trigger an action that prevents further connections**

The idea (as I outlined in the first comment in @A.B's answer) is to inject an additional tcp-forwarding intermediate step on the local host via a no-fork [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/) that "intercepts the incoming forwarded connection from `remotehost`" and runs the `-O cancel` action before completing the forwarding to the final target port. Here are the steps:

1. The first ssh command is similar as in A.B's answer above, but in place of the final target port 22 we use an available non-privileged intermediate port, say 1111:

   ```
   ssh -o ControlMaster=yes -o ControlPath=/tmp/mysshcontrolpath -R 2222:localhost:1111 remotehost
   ```

   (At this point, a connection attempt to port 2222 on `remotehost`
   will fail because it will be forwarded to local side port 1111 and
   port 1111 is not being listened on the local side.)
2. Now run the following on the local host, which upon the first incoming forwarded connection will trigger "cancel further listening on the ssh remote port and complete the current incoming tcp connection":

   ```
   socat tcp4-listen:1111 system:'"ssh -o ControlMaster=no -o ControlPath=/tmp/mysshcontrolpath -O cancel -R 2222:localhost:1111 remotehost && socat - tcp4:localhost:22"',nofork
   ```

   (Here we are assuming that non-interactive ssh authentication has been set up using public key, ssh-agent, etc.)

**A subtle point**. In this setup, a second remote connection will never successfully complete, even during the race window when the first is still initiating. However, this is true only from a high level view (e.g. from above transport layer) in the sense that a second remote connection will never complete *fully forwarding the connection all the way to the final target port on the local machine*.  But from a lower level "firewall" view (e.g. network layer) on `remotehost`, a second connection to the remote forwarding port made during the race window (when the first is still initiating and the cancel action is not yet effective) *will still see a TCP response* (in fact a full TCP handshake will take place), which is distinct from the remote forwarding port not being listened at all on `remotehost`.